# Callback and List<T> losing it's data

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I'm developing an application and i'm using certain API's, one of the methods I most use is this

```
GetData(param1,param2,object UserState, System.Action<AsyncResult<T>> callback {});
```

where everything between `{ }` of result's lambda expression is the callback (correct me if i'm wrong). My problem is this, I have a `List<T>` declared in class level. and when I add items to it throught the callback code everything works fine but when I'm trying to use the List from another point `List<T>` is empty.

Any idea why this is happening ? Any fixes?

Also could someone tell me what userstate used for?

Example usage

```
api.GetData(API.Mirror, id, null, result => { Item b = result.Data; ser.Add(b) }
```

where Item b is the wrapped class and ser is type of Item declared in class level

Comment: Posting your code will be much more useful.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange I'm not allowed to post the code but I can post this as an example usage of my code

   api.GetData(API.Mirror, id, null, result =>
                              {
                                  Item b = result.Data;
                                  ser.Add(b)
  }


where Item b is the wrapped class and ser is type of Item declared in class level

Comment: You're asking us why some method in some unspecified API isn't working as you expect, and you're asking us what some parameter of that method is for based solely on its name?

Comment: @Dimitris Is the list ser static or you pass the reference along?

Comment: @doctorlove you're right I just couldn't find the right expression. I mean using the List<T> from another method in the same class.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I'm giving the method's signature which last parameter is a callback.

Anyway the api can be found here. https://wattvdb.codeplex.com/releases/view/91930
it's the windows phone version.
If you check the tmdb.getseriesbaserecord you'll find the method.

thanks again for your answers

Comment: @RameezAhmedSayad no, the list is not statick

Comment: @Dimitris: Ideally it should work .. if the instance of that class is same while accessing the list .. other possibilities is explicitly setting it empty or clearing..

Answer (score 0):

```
Any idea why this is happening ?
```

With no code to look at, no. But let's guess anyway.

1. You are looking at a member `List<T>` in a different instance of the class
2. The `List<T>` you looked at wasn't actually the member variable (just local to a function)
3. Is this an asynchronous callback and it just hasn't finished/started when you try to use it elsewhere?

Comment: @doctoverlove I gave a part of the code above, it's exactly the same code as in my app only with different variable names.